# How can I align the comment at the end of sentences when the comment predictor is already shown?

Tags: formatting, alignment

I want to align commens on multiple lines neatly, and found [the following question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248621/align-end-of-line-comments-in-vim) (I used the tabular package), but then I found out that it needs the comment specifier NOT to be shown on the same line.

For example, if it is the following line to align the comment:

```
call dein#add("vim-airline/vim-airline") " more info on the bottom
```

It breaks as the align happens on the `"vim-airline...` part, not on the end of the line.

I also found [this question and answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/how-can-i-right-align-end-of-line-comments-with-the-tabular-plugin) but it only work if only one comment specifier is shown before the actual one (in this case there are two, as it quotes the string).

Is it possible to only apply the alignment at the last element of a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) you can use:

```
'<,'>Tabular / ".\{-}$
```

Which will transform

```
call dein#add("scrooloose/nerdcommenter") " more info on the bottom
call dein#add("godlygeek/tabular") " more info on the bottom
call dein#add("tpope/vim-surround") " more info on the bottom
```

To

```
call dein#add("scrooloose/nerdcommenter")  " more info on the bottom
call dein#add("godlygeek/tabular")         " more info on the bottom
call dein#add("tpope/vim-surround")        " more info on the bottom
```

The pattern `/ ".\{-}$` will match a `"` character followed by as few as possible characters (`.\{-}`) until the end of the line `$`). If you don't use tabular but a similar plugin you should be able to use the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any way to define a shortcut of it? `:command Align Tabular / ".\{-}$` caused an error when I saved the `init.vim`, but if I leave `'<.'>`, it does not allow me to use a range (using the `v` key's functionality).

Comment: @Blaszard You want to read [`:h :command-range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand-range)